# Storing items from MySQL into muliple variables

Tags: c#, mysql

I've written a SQL select statement that returns multiple fields from 1 record in the table.

Here is my statement:

```
-- (item_num being the PK)
SELECT item_num, 
       category, 
       weight, 
       cost, 
       description 
  FROM inv 
 WHERE item_num = @inumber;
```

How do I save each field into a variable?

I've seen samples written in while loops but my statement returns ints and chars so I would like to save them to the respectable variables and not an array.

Please bear with me as I'm new to working with database with coding.  I just need to better understand the format.

I've searched for the answer but couldnt have anything related.  Maybe my approach is all wrong.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code where you are executing this against the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your returns will not be ints and chars.  It'll be strings.  At least, that's my experience.  And you should be storing them all in a MySQL datareader.  This will allow you to do something like:

```
List<string> weight = new List<string>();

while(dataReader.Read())
{
     weight.Add(dataReader["weight"]);
}
```

What this does is it will create a list of strings from all the results of your query that were under the "weight" column.  From there, if you need them to be chars and ints, you can convert them.  But I suggest you read up on [MySQL datareaders](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataReader.html).  My example above isn't perfect, but it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you should be using a Datareader and from this it is possible to assign the values directly to the variables;

```
using (var rdr = db.ExecuteReader(cmd))
{
    myIntValue = (int) rdr["IntValue"];
    myStringValue = rdr["StringValue"].ToString();
}
```

However, in your case, my suggestion would be to use a DTO and populate these accordingly from your Data Layer

```
 public class MyDTO
    {
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }
```

and return `IEnumerable<MyDTO>`